# Why my shell script doesn't open the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

All my bash scripts (which I always gave the permission to be executed) works but without open the Konsole.

So if I made the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir t
```

When I double-click it I find a new directory called "t".
And so, all scripts which doesn't contain "sudo".

But If I write

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install vlc -y

#or any othe script with "sudo"
```

The script doesn't work. It doesn't open a shell to asking me the password for using "sudo". And it doesn't install vlc.

It works only if I execute it using terminal, but I need a script which works when I double-click it.

How can I do?

Comment: Why would you expect a command to run in the terminal if you don't tell it to? Simply use `gksudo`. Definitely a dupe of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the terminal from the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e sudo apt-get install vlc -y
```

Other terminals might have a different way how to run a command than `-e`.

Comment: Should I attach "[SOLVED]" ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/198057